# How to determine why unobtrusive validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

Is there a way to trace why unobtrusive validation is not working?

I have disabled all my custom validators, and just using MVC validators, and still it posts back to the server for validation when I click submit.

It's driving me nuts.  The only thing i can think of is that i have a hidden input that has no validation attributes on it other than `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]`.

Is there a specific javascript function i can put a breakpoint in to determine which field is causing the form to submit?

EDIT:

I just realize that only IE8 is causing the server side validation.  IE9, FF, and Chrome all are fine.

EDIT 2:

Ok, it must have been a cache issue or something.  At some point it started working again, and it's still working even after restoring everythng.

Lesson learned.  Alwasy clear you cache when you get goofy problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have reference the following scripts and that the path is correct:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that you have enabled client side validation in your web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

Another important aspect is that if the form has been injected into the DOM as a result of an AJAX call, unobtrusive validation will not be attached to its elements and it will not work. You will have to [**attach it manually**](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) by using the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method in your AJAX success callback after injecting it into the DOM.

Also FireBug's console tab is might be useful in showing potential javascript errors with your code.

Comment: Yes, I have all those in place and validation works fine on other pages.  I don't know why it's not working on this page though, and can't locate which field is causing it.  I see no errors in the console.

Comment: @Mystere Man, how does the view model of this particular form look like?

Comment: I just realized that unobtrusive validation is working fine on FF, Chrome and IE9, but IE8 is going to the server.  Odd.

Comment: @Mystere Man, do you have some javascript code on this page? You are not helping us much without providing details, showing your source code, the view models, the controller action, the view, ... It's hard working with you.

Comment: No custom js code, just the standard jq and unobtrusive stuff.  I am using Modernizr.  I know i'm not helping, but I don't want to post the page because it's client-sensitive.  I'm just trying to figure out what i can trace to figure this out myself.

Comment: @Mystere Man, if you cannot show your code, you will have to narrow down the problem by removing parts of this code until you find what is causing the problem and have a stripped down version allowingto reproduce it. Then there are 2 possibilities: you will know how to solve it or you will show your narrowed down version of the code allowing us to reproduce your problem. Then you will immediately get an answer :-) I promise.

Comment: I'm really just looking for a way to trace this problem myself.  Are you saying that there is no way to do that?

Comment: @Mystere Man, no I am not saying that there is no way. I said that you could start stripping off parts of your code. I mean it works in some pages and not on this particular ones where it works. So ask yourself: how is this page different than the others? Remove unnecessary noise from it. You will end up finding it. At least that's what I would do if I were you. And only ask a question on StackOverflow when you are ready to do so and have sufficient elements. What's the point in asking a question and refusing to show your code? If it is so confidential and secret I don't see how we can help.

Comment: My question was about how to go about debugging this myself.  Not asking for help to identify the problem.  I've already stripped out all non-MS validators (leaving only a required validators).

Comment: Do you really expect a clear and objective answer to this? You said that you removed all non-MS validators, great. Now start striping properties from your view model. Then hardcode simple values in your controller actions. Then strip parts of your view. Until you end up with a working version. That's the answer to your question: `how to go about debugging this myself?`.

Comment: I was looking more for help on where to put breakpoints in the jquery validation, or unobtrusive validation to figure out which element was causing the problem.  I can only strip out so much of the page before it stops working due to architectural issues (in particular, the custom model binder you helped me with a few days ago)

Comment: @Mystere Man, what makes you think that it is a particular element that is causing the problem?